# How to handle a GET/POST request through a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my background script I am essentially trying to block any web request that contains a  tag through regex.(I know this is not optimal but, I'm going to do it anyway.) I believe I have the regex worked out but, I'm trying to figure out how to apply it exactly.

My background script:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {

const regex;

if (details.method === "GET") {

    //Not sure how to handle this part

} else if (details.method === "POST") {

    //Or this part

}
}, {
urls: ["<all_urls>"]
}, ["blocking", "requestBody"]);
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do there. If the problem is how to block a request, you can see the examples in the [official samples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:webrequest) or the documentation.

Comment: If I find a match with my regex in the GET or POST Request I want to block the page

Comment: how do I get the request url to do the matching.

Comment: if (/your-regexp-here/.test(details.url)) return {cancel: true}; [See the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest).

Comment: I tried your suggestion but, that doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to read the documentation but, I find it hard to follow.

Comment: My regex match returns true but, it doesn't block the web page. I'm running on a VM with Chrome's default XSS protection turned off.

Comment: There could be many reasons so guessing one is not productive. Add your manifest.json and the new code in the question.

Comment: After coming back later and looking at my manifest file I seem to have forgotten to add a permission to look at all urls.